# Why are MySQL queries slow on one device but not on another?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm creating a Text-Based RPG using mostly only PHP and MySQL. I experience some slow queries on my laptop, but these same queries are massively faster on my PC, my laptop is a bit older tho. Here are the specs of both, and example of a query, following with what I use.

---

PC: 

->Graphics: NVidia GeForce 1060 3GB

->Processor: Ryzen 3 1300x 3.5GhZ 10MB Cache

->RAM: 8GB DDR4 2400MHz

->SSD: 256GB

//Not sure if those are important

->Database server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB

->Apache: 2.4.27

->Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407

---

Laptop:

->Graphics: Intel HD 3000

->Processor: Intel Pentium 2020M 2.4GHz 2MB Cache

->RAM: 4GB DDR3

->HDD: 512GB

Here's an query example:

```
UPDATE data SET posx = $posX, posy = $posY, last_action = '.time().', current_stamina = $newStamina WHERE id = $id
```

Average time for query like this on my PC is: 0.004 seconds, yet this same query on my laptop takes between 0.4 seconds and 0.1 second. On average it executes somewhere in 0.2 seconds. I consider this very slow for a single simple query. I thought it could've been because of missing indexes, so I've added index for ID, still the same results.

I am not very concerned about my laptops performance, but, what I'm concerned about is if I'm experiencing such slower queries on my laptop, should I expect the same slower queries when I put game on online server? (I do not have one yet)

Problem is that other queries on my laptop are fast (e.g. reading from database or joins).

I know this is very specific kind of thing, so I'm grateful on any info.

Thank you,

Hector

Comment: Short answer.. SSD is much faster then HHD when writing data to disk.. So if you want the server to also write fast you should search webhosting who are using SSD..

Comment: Frankly, the fact that you didn't *already* have an index on ID is concerning, and I'd question virtually every other bit of your setup as a result.

Comment: Well, as far as I know primary_key (ID) is index by being declared as primary key, so I don't think that's the cause.

Comment: In MySQL, the PK _is_ an index, and it is `UNIQUE`.  Adding `INDEX(id)` is a waste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be so many factors to this. First you have less memory on your laptop, which may be important if mariadb is configured the same on pc and laptop, to use more than 4GB of memory for example. This can cause problems. Then, as mentioned, you may have SSD on your PC, but hard disk on you laptop. Then there may be a lot of resident applications running on your laptop, which slows down mysql. Try to compare the configuration of mysql on both devices, check how many processes are running on both, check the IO times on the laptop.
You most probably don't have to worry for putting you app online and have slow queries - those servers are configured well and definitely simple update shouldn't be a problem.